# how to run a powershell script as administrator

Tags: windows-7, powershell

On my Windows 7 Desktop, I have script.ps1, which needs admin privileges (it starts a service).  I want to click on this script and run it with admin privileges.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it, with the help of an additional icon on your desktop.  I guess you could move the script someone else if you wanted to only have a single icon on your desktop.

1. Create a shortcut to your Powershell script on your desktop
2. Right-click the shortcut and click **Properties**
3. Click the **Shortcut** tab
4. Click **Advanced**
5. Select **Run as Administrator**

You can now run the script elevated by simple double-clicking the new shortcut on your desktop.

Comment: This worked for me, but **Run as Administrator** only became available after adding `powershell -f ` in front of the script path, so as to "complete" the command…

Comment: @mousio - I needed this too, thanks for the comment

Comment: @mousio can you tell me why that command works?

Comment: @SShaheen - for **Run as Administrator** to become available, the shortcut needs to point to some sort of executable (e.g. powershell.exe) instead of just the document or script the shortcut originally pointed to. A shortcut to `script.ps1` works, as does a shortcut to `powershell.exe -f script.ps1`, but the latter can be set to run as administrator (see `powershell.exe /?` for the explanation of the `-f` or `-File` switch)

Comment: I use it to start the powershell console as administrator. A similar result is to create a ps1 file with `Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs`.

Comment: I don't get why this is upvoted when the shortcut has to point to the exe instead of the script.

Answer (score 53):

On UAC-enabled systems, to make sure a script is running with full admin privileges, add this code at the beginning of your script:

```
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } else {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}

'running with full privileges'
```

Now, when running your script, it will call itself again and attempt to elevate privileges before running.
The -elevated switch prevents it from repeating if something fails.

You may remove the `-noexit` switch if the terminal should automatically close when the script finishes.

Comment: If script requires arguments-parameters ?

Comment: what if this tells me it is running with full privileges, but my code still says insufficient administrative privileges?

Comment: @Kiquenet add it into the `param(...)` on top and forward them right before `-elevated`, you'll need to be clever about how you build the `ArgumentList`, probably will want to use the `String[]` form.

Comment: pretty nifty - better than creating a shortcut

Comment: Thank you SO much, this has saved me! Little caveat: The "-noexit" flag may be nice for debugging, but perhaps undesired behavior in production...

Comment: Can anyone please explain this code step by step ideally with the help of comments like we usually do in powershell files? I am not an expert and started learning ps recently. Thank you. I used the code and it worked fine.

Comment: @user11702680 I suggest you research each command and provide the comments as an update to the answer. I would gladly approve.

Answer (score 18):

if you are in the same powershell you could do this:

```
Start-Process powershell -verb runas -ArgumentList "-file fullpathofthescript"
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it changes the working directory for the called script to `C:\Windows\System32`. An alternative which preserves the current directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033941/2441655

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [MDMoore313's answer above](https://superuser.com/a/532109/1340418):

If we want to execute the commands in the same working directory as we are currently in, we have to add a few things:

```
#### START ELEVATE TO ADMIN #####
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$shouldAssumeToBeElevated,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String]$workingDirOverride
)

# If parameter is not set, we are propably in non-admin execution. We set it to the current working directory so that
#  the working directory of the elevated execution of this script is the current working directory
if(-not($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('workingDirOverride')))
{
    $workingDirOverride = (Get-Location).Path
}

function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

# If we are in a non-admin execution. Execute this script as admin
if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($shouldAssumeToBeElevated) {
        Write-Output "Elevating did not work :("

    } else {
        #                                                         vvvvv add `-noexit` here for better debugging vvvvv 
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -file "{0}" -shouldAssumeToBeElevated -workingDirOverride "{1}"' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition, "$workingDirOverride"))
    }
    exit
}

Set-Location "$workingDirOverride"
##### END ELEVATE TO ADMIN #####

# Add actual commands to be executed in elevated mode here:
Write-Output "I get executed in an admin PowerShell"
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it's sitting onto your desktop, I'd say the most effortless way to get this done is dragging it onto the [elevation gadget](http://blogs.technet.com/elevationpowertoys/archive/2009/12/17/elevation-gadget-2-0.aspx).

Otherwise you could make a separate script using [the `elevate` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight.aspx) on your ps1  script.

Or, you could apply `elevate` just to the service-starting bit.

Comment: please share some sample one liner code :)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell ISE lives at %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe. You can right-click that and select "Run as administrator" and run the script from in there.

You can also find it under the Windows Logo > All Programs > Accessories > Windows PowerShell and do the same thing with those shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an option to launch a Powershell script as adminstrator, directly from the Explorer context-menu, see section 2 of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033941/2441655

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo
```

Why does it have to take 30+ lines of code to do what 4 characters do?

So here, write a .bat file to invoke your script, in it use the:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers only tells you if the script is running from an admin. If starting the same script with elevated privileges, the user is still not admin.

A parameter which can be used to determine this is the following :

```
if (($myinvocation.UnboundArguments.Contains("-elevated")) -or ($testadmin -eq $true)) {
   #Good to go with Admin rights

} else {
    #Start with elevated privs

}
```

I've not been able to find a parameter that detects the Powershell environment has been started with Admin privileges.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the beginning of the script:

```
$currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$testadmin = $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
if ($testadmin -eq $false) {
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
exit $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a subset of [MDMoore313’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/108207/150988#532109), from over four years ago.