# How can I create a database in PostgreSQL on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, database, postgresql

I use Windows 7 on my own home computer. I have installed PostgreSQL and now I would like to create an database.

I tried with `createdb mydatabase` but I got this error message:

```
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL: role "Jonas" does
not exist
```

I have also tried to create a role "Jonas" with `createuser Jonas` but I got the same error, even if I was logged in as Administrator in PowerShell.

How can I create a PostgreSQL database on my Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/tutorial-createdb.html

> Another response could be this:
>
> ```
> createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  user "joe" does not
> exist
> ```
>
> where your own login name is mentioned. This will happen if the administrator has not created a PostgreSQL user account for you. (PostgreSQL user accounts are distinct from operating system user accounts.) If you are the administrator, see Chapter 18 for help creating accounts. **You will need to become the operating system user under which PostgreSQL was installed (usually postgres) to create the first user account**.

Comment: I tried to start PowerShell as Administrator and then execute `createuser Jonas` but I got the same error message.

Comment: Did you try to start PowerShell as `postgres`?

Comment: No, how can I do that? I asked a related [question](http://superuser.com/questions/220144/how-can-i-run-commands-in-powershell-with-administrator-permissions/220150#220150) to solve this, but that only works for `Administrator`.

Comment: It worked when I started PowerShell with `runas /user:ComputerName\postgres powershell` and then executed `createuser Jonas`

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/tutorial-createdb.html

> It could also be that you were assigned a PostgreSQL user name that is
>   different from your operating system user name; in that case you need
>   to use the -U switch or set the PGUSER environment variable to specify
>   your PostgreSQL user name.

I met the same problem, now I do it with

```
createdb -U postgres dbname
```