# How to run script as administrator?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, administrator

I'm looking to do what's asked in this question: [how to run a powershell script as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/108207/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-administrator)

The accepted answer says to use a shortcut. I'd like to do that, but when I get into Advanced Properties, everything is grayed out.  How do I get around this?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Are you logged in with an unpriviledged account? Is the shortcut located on your desktop?

Comment: duplicate: https://superuser.com/a/1366964/235752

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick is to edit the Shortcut target to add `powershell.exe` in front of the script path so it looks something like this:

```
powershell.exe -file "H:\Powershell\MyPoshScript.ps1"
```

Click OK, then go back into Properties and the "Run as Administrator" box will now be changeable.

(note: when I did this, Windows fixed the powershell.exe reference to the full path.

Comment: This worked great!

Comment: This is not working for me.  I changed from .bat to .ps1 and still under the compatibility tab, run as administrator is grayed out.

Comment: Instead of using the compatibility tab (where the option is greyed out ) use the Advanced button on the Shortcut Tab