# Run as Administrator greyed out on shortcut

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, administrator

I have a shortcut to a program that only works when run as administrator but in the shortcuts advanced options "always run as administrator" is greyed out. I've looked at the other similar questions but none apply to my issue. UAC is enabled, I am an administrator and i have no idea how to run it in cmd.

Comment: The program is in a network? Programs in a network won't run as administrator.

Comment: Of course you would prefer to set & forget "always run as administrator", but, until you get that working, you can right click the icon and select "run as administrator,", although you will have to do that every time that your want to run it.

Comment: @Earendul The program isnt in a network.

Comment: @Mawg I'm not sure why but right click the shortcut doesn't bring up the option to run as admin, even though i can click the original .exe and run that as admin

Comment: Can you start it from the command line by using an elevated command prompt? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @Mawg Like i said in the question, I have no idea how to run it in cmd

Comment: Does right click offer nothing at all? If you can select Properties, then Target will give you the command line that you need.

Comment: Make a new user admin account and log into it, does it still have the issue?

Comment: @Mawh I can right click it to see the target but I still don't know how to run it in cmd.

Comment: @Moab I tried to follow your advice but it wouldn't let me create a new admin account as it is a work PC.

Comment: Since it is a work PC, contact your computer administrator about the issue.

Comment: @Moab I did but its not exactly on their priority list. It'd be quicker to wait for a new pc.

Comment: @man-qa - Sounds like you are not actually an `Administrator` domain permissions overrule your local permissions.

Comment: What level is your UAC set to? The always run as administrator is usually only greyed out if UAC is set too low. It should be set to "Notify me when applications try to make changes to my computer (default)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be able to use the run as administrator available on the compatibility tab.

One way third party way would be with nircmd. 
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#elevate

Comment: The author indicated this option is grayed out.

Comment: No they did not. They stated the option was greyed out on the advanced options on the shortcut tab. I was referring to the spot on the compatibility tab.

Comment: @birdman3131 Wow i didn't expect this to work but it did. Thanks birdman :)

Answer (score 13):

> It works if you add the executable to the shortcut target.
> For example:
>
> Right-click on the shortcut and change the target from:
>
> C:\Scripts\helloworld.js
>
> to
>
> wscript.exe C:\Scripts\helloworld.js
>
> (or)
>
> cscript.exe C:\Scripts\helloworld.js
>
> Then the Run as Administrator checkbox is activated in properties.

Eg:

for a python script add in the target field:

`"C:\Users\......\Python36\python.exe" "C:\Users\......\test.py"`

For PowerShell script add this in the target:

`powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\A path with spaces\MyScript.ps1'"`

(if you want to also pass some args see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10137272/1486850))

Don't forget to check the "run as admin" after...

All the glory to [Ramesh Srinivasan](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/advanced-propertiesrun-as-administrator-option-is/c67e3a87-bc7a-4050-af5a-228b8cccdd9d?db=5)

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though the "run as administrator" context menu option and/or shortcut checkbox are unavailable for batch files/scripts.
This was answered for PowerShell here:
[How to run script as administrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/401616/how-to-run-script-as-administrator?rq=1)

I don't have an answer yet for running a common batch file.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happen when a shortcut points to an object identifier rather than a directory path.

You can tell if this is the case because the target in the shortcut properties is something like `{0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}` instead of a directory path.

If you want to create a shortcut to something in `C:\Windows\System32`, create the shortcut directly off an item in that folder, rather than trying to create it from an existing shortcut on the start menu.

Comment: That's not the only way this can happen; I think it can also happen when you need admin in order to modify the shortcut file.  At any rate, I'm seeing this with a path-based shortcut that was put on my start menu by an installer.  Oh, it could also be because the target is an `.ini` file, not an executable...

Comment: When I try creating a shortcut to hosts, it says cannot create shortcut here, would you like it on the desktop instead; but why am I suffering through this even when I am admin on this box ??

Comment: I have this problem on a python script shortcut

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happen with file types windows doesn't recognize/trust.  But I just found a simple solution for this.

Make a shortcut to cmd.exe (c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe), and replace the Target field with this

```
C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start "" "c:\path\to\your.file"
```

Now you should be able to enable the "Run as administrator" on the Advanced tab

Caveats:

- On windows 10, running as administrator seems to have a different set of network drives, try to use absolute UNC paths rather than mapped drives
- If you need to pass parameters please [check here](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
  for some documentation for the Start command

Why do we use `Start` instead of just opening it with cmd.exe?

- If you just run the file using a shortcut to `cmd.exe /c c:\path\to\your.file`, you're stuck with an empty black window open so long as your program is running

How does using `Start` work around this?

1. It starts a cmd instance with the `/c` flag which closes it after it's command finishes running
2. It then runs `Start` which is a native command in cmd.exe that opens a "program" in a new window
3. The way the `Start` command works if it's not an executable the launch gets passed up to Windows, which then opens it using the associated program for that file type
4. Once the launch is started, the `Start` command ends which then lets the cmd.exe window close

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to create a shortcut to the executable that needs to be run as admin (if you want to workaround the ugly code for invoking the UAC prompt). After creating the new shortcut, right-click on it and select *Properties*, then click the *Shortcut* tab, then the *Advanced...* button and finally check the *Run as Administrator* checkbox.

Comment: This is a nice little workaround. I was able to make a shortcut to my "hosts" file using this technique with Visual Studio Code. Example shortcut: `"C:\Users\quantastical\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the properties of shortcut file
2. Click on shortcut tab
3. add "powershell.exe" before the path of file in Target

it should look like below:

powershell.exe -file "H:\Powershell\MyPoshScript.ps1"

4. Click apply
5. Click advance button
6. Run as administrator now selectable.
7. Check Run as administrator and apply --> OK

Done

reference from:
[How to run script as administrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/401616/how-to-run-script-as-administrator?rq=1)

Comment: This option worked for me trying to start a service. Shortcuts to both a batch file running `net start Spooler` and a Powershell script running `Start-Service Spooler` both had `Run as Administrator` greyed out. Changing the shortcut target to `cmd.exe /c "blah"` and `powershell.exe -file "blah"` worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution (example for Word 2016, Windows 10)

1. Don't use the regular shortcut
2. Find the main file (for Word 2016 : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE")
3. Make a shortcut with "Send to the desktop as a shortcut"
4. Now you will see that "Always run as an administrator" option is not greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 system when running shortcuts to run batch files/VBScripts to sync and eject USB disks, or to shutdown Hyper-V systems in preparation for staff to reboot the server cleanly.

Found when I right-clicked the icon, selected properties, then selected the Advanced button next to Change Icon. Select the Run As Administrator option then Save. If UAC is enabled, it will still ask for permission to run, but it will now run properly.

Answer (score 0):

My icon was copied to the quick launch bar. The option to run as administrator was greyed out. So I started again and I deleted the shortcut i had previously tried to set.

**This is how i solved the issue.**

Opened my start menu, found the icon I wanted, properties, open file location. 
(This opened the file location of the shortcut from my start menu - perfect).

Now I selected the shortcut icon and copied it.

I then right click on my quick launch bar, "Open Folder" and pasted a copy of my shortcut there.

Now I have access to set it to run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

[BrianD](https://superuser.com/users/571070/briand) gave the best answer and [Ross](https://superuser.com/users/200385/ross) in [How to run script as administrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/401616/how-to-run-script-as-administrator) explained it:

> Instead of using the compatibility tab (where the option is greyed out
>   ) use the Advanced button on the Shortcut Tab

This is valid for Windows7 at least.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for Control Panel to "Run as admin", but it was greyed out for a standard user. Solved by opening C:\Windows\System32, right-clicked on Control and created the shortcut on the desktop. Now this shortcut is available with "Run as administrator" on right-click.

Comment: Your question does not directly answer the question. Please add it as a comment to the question instead.