# Powershell script with elevated permissions still has insufficient permissions

Tags: permissions, powershell, uac

i have actually had this running before like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/108207/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-administrator/532109?noredirect=1#comment1730997_532109) but for some reason, I am getting the message "running with full privileges" but still my script throws an exception:

```
get-brokersession : Insufficient administrative privilege

 + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied:
```

My Script:

```
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin {
  $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
  $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) 
    {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } 
    else {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
}

exit
}

'running with full privileges'

$hostname=$args[0]
$Logfile = "C:\Program Files\NSClient++\log\logout_user.log"
$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")

Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

Add-PSSnapin Citrix.*
get-brokersession -HostedMachineName $hostname -filter {sessionstate -eq "Disconnected"} | stop-brokersession
LogWrite "$Stamp Server: $hostname - stopped brokersessions, inactive Users cleared"
Write-Host "Server: $hostname - stopped brokersessions, inactive Users cleared"
```

edit: The service which runs the script is running with a managed-service account which has local admin permissions on this machine.
like I said, it worked before, I'm not sure what changed.. if anything changed at all..

edit2: this question is rather asking for why I can not run the commands even though I should have full privileges rather than how to elevate my privileges. Hope this is enough to justify a new question

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run a powershell script as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/108207/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-administrator)

Comment: @Ramhound ..edited.. :)